# How to insert radio button and hyperlink in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Here is my html

```
<table id="template_table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Template Number</th>
            <th>Message Kind</th>
            <th>Template Name</th>
            <th>Preview</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Template Number</th>
            <th>Message Kind</th>
            <th>Template Name</th>
            <th>Preview</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

JS:

```
        $('#template_table').DataTable({
            "data": EMAIL_TEMPLATES,
            "columns": [
                { "data": null },
                { "data": "subDirectory" },
                { "data": "msgKind" },
                { "data": "templateName" },
                { "data": null }
            ]
        });
```

I want to add radio button at first column (Select) with value `'msgKind/subDirectory'` and hyperlink at last column (Preview) whose href will be `'some_domain/msgKind/subDirectory'`

can anyone help?

Comment: Just create a property for EMAIL_TEMPLATES to hold it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it by creating new properties for EMAIL_TEMPLATES

```
            for (var i=0;  i<EMAIL_TEMPLATES.length; i++) {
                var template_path = EMAIL_TEMPLATES[i]['msgKind'] + '/' + EMAIL_TEMPLATES[i]['subDirectory'];
                EMAIL_TEMPLATES[i]['preview'] = '<a target="_blank" href="some_domain/' + template_path + '">Preview</a>';
                EMAIL_TEMPLATES[i]['radio_button'] = '<input type="radio" name="selected_template" value='+ template_path + '>';
            }
            $('#template_table').DataTable({
                data: EMAIL_TEMPLATES,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "radio_button" },
                    { "data": "subDirectory" },
                    { "data": "msgKind" },
                    { "data": "templateName" },
                    { "data": "preview" },
                ]
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code for adding any kind of html in data table columns 
Here is your code :)

```
$('#template_table').DataTable({
        "data": EMAIL_TEMPLATES,
        "columns": [
            {
               mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                  return '<input type="radio" name="gender" value="msgKind/subDirectory">';
               }

            },
            { "data": "subDirectory" },
            { "data": "msgKind" },
            { "data": "templateName" },
            {
               mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                  return '<a href="some_domain/msgKind/subDirectory">Preview</a>';
               }

            },
        ]
    });
```

Comment: thanks this is helpfull. but i want to use dynamic value for  radio button and hyperlink. want to use msgKind and SubDirectoory values here. How can i do this?

Comment: You can use the gloabal variable "row" that is passing in mRender method,  row.msgKind and row.SubDirectoory